# im trying to make a little game, but my loop in android will not work

Tags: java, android

This is what should happen:

from the 16 buttons one gets selected randomly and its color turns red.
the player then has to click on it
then it turns black again and another one is selected.
after 5 times the activity should end and with the intent the game over activity should be started.

unfortunately after clicking on the first red button, I immediatly get to the game over screen. (which is still blank)

this is the code, and thanks for your help already now!

```
package com.example.sixteenbuttons;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        //aufgabe1
        for (int i = 1; i < 17; i++) {
            final Button button = new Button(this);
            button.setText("Button " + i);
            layout.addView(button);
        }
        setRandom();
        setRedButton();
        newRedButton();
    }

    int currentRandom;
    public void setRandom() {
        Random random = new Random();
        LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        currentRandom = random.nextInt(layout.getChildCount() - 1);
    }
    public void setRedButton() {
        LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        Button winButton = (Button)layout.getChildAt(currentRandom);
        winButton.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
    public void newRedButton() {
        for (int i=0; i<=5;i++){
            LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
            final Button winButton = (Button)layout.getChildAt(currentRandom);
            winButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Klick auf " + winButton.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    setRandom();
                    setRedButton();
                    winButton.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    newRedButton();
                }
            });
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GameOverActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: remove for loop and after each click produce a new red button. also, define a variable to keep the counter for you till it gets 5.